# How do u manually put in the address for bookmark?

Tags: bookmarks

some sites change the address as soon as you go there and if you bookmark it, it doesn't come out as the one you wanted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by your other questions I'm assuming you're using Mozilla Firefox.

In Firefox, right click a spot on the bookmarks toolbar or bookmarks menu drop-down and select **New Bookmark...** and fill in the fields yourself, then click **Add**.

If you've already added a bookmark, and it is using the wrong address, you can right click it from the menu or toolbar and select **properties** then modify the address it's using.

Comment: That's true, but I don't really discriminate between people who accept their answers or not. This will benefit the community as a whole and other people who find this question from search engines etc.